# Is the principle of transfinite induction (PTI) always not true on a set that is not well ordered?

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-induction

It seems obvious to me that if for any domino (it is known that all previous dominos fell than this domino will also fell) than it is true that all dominos will fell. It should not matter if there is an infinity of dominos before any domino. Why then the PTI is not true on sets that are not well ordered? It seems to me I understood the proof which indeed shows that PTI is not true when the property in PTI is that x does not belong to B (set that is not well ordered). But is PTI true in my domino example? Is there a way to show that PTI may not be true in domino example? It seems to me that domino example covers all cases.

Comment: Consider the real line with the usual ordering, and let $P(x)$ denote the statement $x\le0$. Note that, if $P(y)$ holds for all $y\lt x$, then $P(x)$ also holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every linearly ordered set has a largest well-ordered initial segment (which may as well be empty). Call this segment $S$, and consider the property $x\in S$.

Take any point outside of $S$, if such point exists, $y$, then it holds for every $x<y$ $$\forall u(u<x\to u\in S)\to x\in S,$$
because $S$ is an initial segment, and if $x\notin S$, then there is some $u<x$ such that $u\notin S$ as well. Because $S$ is the largest well-ordered initial segment.

Therefore, if PTI holds, $S$ must be everything, and so well-ordered.

---

Of course, this talks about linear orders. We can talk about partial orders, and the same idea works out with a well-founded downwards-closed subset. So we get that well-foundedness to be equivalent to having a recursion property.

Comment: "Every linearly ordered set has a largest well-ordered initial segment"? A set of all integers is linealy ordered but does not have a largest well-ordered segment (with minimal element). What do you mean by initial segment?

Comment: The empty set, as I said.

Comment: But empty set is not the largest well-ordered segment of linearly ordered set, such as Z. Segment of a set is just a subset of a set? It looks like you state that if PTI holds than the set is well-ordered. But it is not true - I gave you the domino example with infinite numbers of dominos at the left of any domino.

Comment: It is the largest **initial segment**. Any other **initial segment** contains infinitely many negative integers and is therefore not well-ordered.

Comment: the set with only number 1 is larger than empty set, but well-ordered

Comment: But is it an **initial segment**?

Comment: Initial segment of a set is a set composed of all elements preceding to the elements of this set? Ok, than it is an empty set for Z. This is clear now. Or may be I am wrong?

Comment: No, that's correct. An initial segment is downwards closed, and indeed for $\Bbb Z$ it is the empty set, yes. But for example, the interval $[0,1]$ in $\Bbb R$ has a maximal initial segment which is $\{0\}$ that is well-ordered.

Comment: only now I got it), initial segment of a set is just any "starting" subset of a set, it could be a whole set or empty set.

Comment: you wrote "Take any point outside of S, if such point exists, y, then it holds for it.." but later you never mention point y in the formular

Comment: Yes, thanks. Let me fix that quickly.

Comment: You proved that for any linear order A, if for this particular property (x∈S) the PTI is true, than A should be well-ordered. It seems to me it does not answer my question. Is it possible to find a situation when the PTI also does hold, but A is not well-ordered? I think my domino example is exactly this situation. ∀x(∀y(y<x⟹P(y))⟹P(x)) where P(x)="domino fells" and A=Z. Is it correct? So I did found a situation when PTI is true but A is not well-ordered? So the answer to the title of my question is No? There is a situation when the set is not well-ordered but PTI holds?

Comment: What do you mean? You're asking for some statement that holds for PTI even when the set is not well-ordered? The statement $x\leq x$ or $x=x$ or $\exists y(x=y\lor x\neq y)$ are all examples of such statements. If your question is about the general PTI, I have shown here that PTI holds if and only if the initial segment which is well-ordered is equal to the whole linear order, which means (in particular) the order is a well-order. If this doesn't really answer your question, I suggest you edit your question and add a clarification so that people can understand what you're really after.

Comment: The problem is that it contradicts to the theorem: PTI is equivalent to well-orderness. That is why I'm perplexed.

Comment: No I am not asking for the statement. I am asking: is that always true that if PTI holds for a set (A,<), than (A,<) should be well ordered (have a minimal element)? It looks that you gave an example that contradicts this statement. But it is a well known theorem (it was on a lecture: well-orderness is equivalent to PTI). My domino example also contradicts this theorem.

Comment: Yes. As I wrote in my answer, and repeatedly in the comment. Take that one instance, of belonging to the largest well-ordered initial segment. If that instance is true, then the set has to be equal to this well-ordered initial segment.

Comment: I agree that if PTI is true for this particular instance then the set should be well-ordered. But is it always true that when PTI is true for any other instance then the set should be well-ordered? Yes or no? The theorem says yes, but several examples here say No. For example x=x (as you wrote), A=Z. Z is clearly not well ordered. May be I do not understand the theorem: well-ordering is equivalent to the principle of transfinite induction. Does this theorem mean that if PTI is true then the set should be well-ordered?

Comment: The theorem is not "If there is any single one instance for PTI, then the order is well-ordered". It is "If PTI holds for all instances, then the order is well-ordered", and my answer tells you that indeed there is one "type of instance" which is enough to check.

Comment: I had a moment of hapiness! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The induction principle for well-ordered sets is the following theorem: Let $(X,<)$ be a well-ordered set and let $P(x)$ be a statement pertaining to elements $x$ of $X$. (It can be itentified with the subset $P(X):=\{ x \in X \ | \ P(x)\}$ of $X$). Assume that the following statement holds:

> $\forall x(\forall y(y<x\Longrightarrow P(y)) \Longrightarrow P(x))$

Then $\forall z P(z)$ holds. In other words, if $P(x)$ holds for $x$ whenever $P(y)$ holds for all $y<x$, then $P(z)$ holds for all $z$.

Consider a linearly ordered set $(X,<)$ which is not well-ordered. So there is a non-empty subset $Y \subseteq X$ which has no minimum. Consider the statement $P(x): \forall y \in Y,x<y$. Let $x \in X$ such that for all $z\in X$ we have $z<x\Longrightarrow P(z)$. I claim that $P(x)$ holds. Indeed assume for contradiction that there is $y \in Y$ with $y\leq x$. Since $Y$ has no minimum, we may assume that $y<x$. So $P(y)$ holds by our hypothesis. In particular we have $y<y$: a contradiction. We deduce that $P(x)$ holds.

But of course the statement $\forall z P(z)$ is false since $P(y)$ is false when $y \in Y$ and $Y$ is non-empty. So the induction principle fails for $(X,<)$.